# Auto complete from JSON does not display correctly- I get values but are displayed as blanks

Tags: javascript, css, json, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to render auto complete from the server-side (source: JSON). There is an error in displaying rendered suggestions. They appear blank though they seem to render the expected values.  This seems to be a purely display issue but I cannot figure out the source of the error

Here is the code I used in my html file.

```
    <link href="/css/edwave-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

 // Below is the name of the textfield that will be autocomplete    
    $('#university').autocomplete({

            minLength: 2,
 // The below ruby code returns the JSON which i have checked up, [{"name":"Stanford University"},{"name":"Santa Clara University"}]

            source: '<%= university_path %>',
  // This updates the textfield when you move the updown the suggestions list, with your keyboard. In our case it will reflect the same value that you see in the suggestions which is the person.given_name.
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                $('#university').val(ui.item.name);
                return false;
            },

            select: function(event, ui) {

                $('#university').val(ui.item.name);

                            return false;
            }
        })
     // The below code is straight from the jQuery example. It formats what data is displayed in the dropdown box, is something wrong in this?

            .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )

                    .append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };

    });
    </script>

<input id="university" name="university" type="text" />
```

My JSON which I have used for my source looks like this (what is returned from my Ruby controller).The error i get is attached

```
[{"name":"Stanford University"},{"name":"Santa Clara University"}]
```

I have tried the following:

1. I changed the JQuery UI file from my custom to a standard theme. It still gives me the display issue.
2. I removed all other JS and CSS files included in the html page and only included the following to make sure there is no interference, it still gives me the issue. 
   [image]
3. I tried running the auto-complete purely from front-end using the JQuery UI plugin- see code below. It seems to work fine with this. However, I need to run this from the back-end.

   ```
   <script>

   $(function() {
       var universityTags = [ "Stanford University",  "Santa Clara University"];
       $( "#university" ).autocomplete({
           source: universityTags
       });
   });

   </script>
   ```

Is the JS code I have written in my html fine? Why is the rendered display not showing me results?

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle with your JSON file attached.

Comment: Please show HTML code of the generated page (at least the part with $('#university').autocomplete statement)

Comment: @MitchellLayzell - i am not too used to fiddle, so i have created a very basic one with my sample code i am trying to break, do you see the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/venomoustoad/9yBcZ/

Comment: @phil.ts - the generated code in the source is the same as code above with one exception, the *source: '<%= university_path %>'* is replaced by *source: '/university'* - when I run the /university link, i get the JSON object as attached in the JSfiddle in the above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue - the issue was in the jquery autocomplete call.
It should have been "***ui-autocomplete***" instead of just "***autocomplete***" as in the code below for the last section of the Javascript code:

```
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )

                .append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<%= university_path %>` without quotes:

```
source: <%= university_path %>,
```

Comment: does not work- the quotes are apparently necessary as the autocomplete is functioning, but only without the rendered display